# Is it bad practice to declare a class' constructor 'final' in PHP?

Tags: php, class, constructor, final

If I have a parent class that is extended by lots and lots of other classes, and I want to make sure the parent class's constructor is ALWAYS run, is it a bad idea to declare the constructor `final`?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
class ParentClass {

    public final function __construct() {

        //parent class initialization...

        $this->construct();

    }

    protected function init() {

        echo 'constructing<br>';

    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    protected function init() {

        //child class initialization

        echo 'constructing child<br>';

    }

}
```

that way the child class can have a sort-of constructor, and the parent class's constructor will always execute. Is this bad practice?

Comment: I understand why you don't trust PHP programmers, but I don't understand why you care :-)

Comment: I'm just trying to be explicit with my code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declaring a `final` `__construct` ensures that no one who extends your class can implement a method with the same name. On the surface of it, this would seem like it would mean no one else can declare a constructor for sub-classes of this class, but this is not true, since the PHP 4 style of `ClassName()` still works just fine as an alternate name for the constructor. So really, declaring a constructor as final gets you nothing in PHP.

Comment: that's true, I hadn't considered that. Would the parent class's `__construct` method still be called though? Or would the child class's constructor of a different name just override it?

Comment: Parent constructors are never called automatically. You would still have to call `parent::__construct()` or `parent::ClassName()` in the child class constructor.

Answer (score 6):

As of PHP 5.3.3, I have tested this with 5.6 and 7.0, declaring the `__construct` method of a class `final` will prevent any child class overriding the constructor either using `__construct` or the PHP 4 style of `ClassName()` (note that the PHP 4 style is deprecated as of PHP 7). Preventing a child class declaring a constructor will ensure that the parent constructor is always called. This will, of course, not allow any child classes to implement their own constructor logic. There would definitely be practical use cases for this though I would not recommend it as good practice generally.

Some examples:

Without declaring `__construct` final

```
class ParentClassWithoutFinal {
    private $value = "default";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->value = static::class;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

class ChildClassA extends ParentClassWithoutFinal {
    public function __construct() {
        // Missing parent::__construct();
    }
}

echo (new ChildClassA()); // ouput: default
```

With final `__construct`

```
class ParentClassWithFinal extends ParentClassWithoutFinal {
    public final function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class ChildClassB extends ParentClassWithFinal {
}

echo (new ChildClassB()); // output: ChildClassB
```

Trying to declare `__construct` in a child class

```
class ChildClassC extends ParentClassWithFinal {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}

// Fatal error: Cannot override final method ParentClassWithFinal::__construct()
```

Trying to declare `ClassName()` constructor in a child class

```
class ChildClassD extends ParentClassWithFinal {
    public function ChildClassD() {
    }
}

// Fatal error: Cannot override final ParentClassWithFinal::__construct() with ChildClassD::ChildClassD()
// Also in PHP 7: Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ChildClassD has a deprecated constructor
```

Answer (score -1):

After finalizing the constructor, you can't pass any variables to initializing function. It  forces users of you class to use globals as settings for their child classes.

In Zend Framework using overridable init() is common practice, but I've never seen finalizing a constructor there.

Comment: Really? I just tried it and I could pass a variable from the finalized constructor to the child initializing function and echo it

Comment: oh, I mean, user can't pass any unforseen parameter

Comment: However, ZF is moving to passing around config objects as a means of standardizing how parameters are passed between objects.

Comment: Yeah, it's another solution, if he really wants to finalize his constructor